# Как использовать переменную в функции?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('li').click(function() {
  n = $(this).attr('class');
  c = parseInt(n.substr(1, 1)) + 1;
  l = '.L' + c;
  $(this).nextAll().each(function(i, el) {
    if ($(el).hasClass("L1")) {
      return false;
    }
    if ($(el).hasClass("L2")) {
      $(this).slideToggle(250)
    }
  });
})
```

Хочется вместо "L2" использовать переменную l . Подскажите как.

Answer (score 1):

> Хочется вместо "L2" использовать переменную l

Хочется? Так подставляй её:

```
$('li').click(function(){    
    n=$(this).attr('class');
    c=parseInt(n.substr(1,1))+1;
    l='L'+c; // Заметь, точка тут не ставится впереди, раз это используется в hasClass
    $(this).nextAll().each(function(i, el){
        if($(el).hasClass("L1")){return false;}
        if($(el).hasClass(l)){$(this).slideToggle(250)}
    });    
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто используете переменную l, только для того что бы отработал hasClass необходимо убрать точку в сложении

```
l='L'+c;
```

Comment: Спасибо ! То ли кодил я уставший, то ли еще чего... Не заметил.